# Putting Heading within 2 horizontal lines in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to put an h3 heading between 2 pairs of horizontal line
just like that :
[image]

Anyone help me with the idea to implement 
that in html,css

---

**UPDATE**

Please how can I do this but with an anchor tag ( actually a button )
I want it to be just like that:

[image]

Comment: sorry bro english is my second language :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could style a pseudoelement, like so : http://jsbin.com/epeceb/1/

CSS

```
h3 {
  width: 500px;
  font: 30px Arial;
  font-weight: normal; 
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

h3 span {
  background: #fff; 
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

h3:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -4px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px double red;
}
```

---

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. By default, or from some style resets, the `z-index` of `h3` may be `auto`. In that case `h3 { zindex: 0; }` is required to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this, is to make the two lines in css, have a div absolute that will go over the lines with a white background. Should work perfectly.

Comment: +1 This is how I would do it too. The only issue is if you have a textured background. You can make the lines with borders on pseudo-elements, for instance.

Comment: mmmmm nice idea Stephen , Actually i'm going to try that :)
Thanks !