# Putting Button within divider in css

Tags: css, button, divider

I wanna implement this idea by css :
[image]

What is the best approach to do that in CSS ?
Thanks very much !!

**UPDATE**

I've did this trick before with Headings , More information here :
[Putting Heading within 2 horizontal lines in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961952/putting-heading-within-2-horizontal-lines-in-css/16962084#16962084)

But when i tried to edit the heading version also didn't work with buttons .

Comment: Sorry didn't post that , i'll update it now

Comment: Sorry but it's still very unclear what you're after? You just want a right-align `check more` with rounded borders?

Comment: you cant see the grey divider ?

Comment: khalid, I see this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0xU6j.png - Nothing Grey...

Comment: @Basic
I can see grey divider :D
Indeed that just because our screen brightness is diffrent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pB9MY/

```css
body { background: #fff;  }

h3 {
  width: 500px;
  font: 30px Arial;
  font-weight: normal; 
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

h3 span {
  background: #fff; 
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

h3:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 8px solid grey;
  opacity:.2
}
button{
  background-color:green;
  border:1px solid green;
  border-radius:5px;
  vertical-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3><span><button>Hello</button></span></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well it's nice of you to _explain_ your answer

Comment: Thanks very much , that's what i wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

Create a div for the text...

```
<div class="rightrounded">Some Text</div>
```

And apply the appropriate css...

```
.rightrounded {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #008000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4FY6/)

Comment: No man , focus at the image , there's a horizontal grey divider